# Why is the window empty when I run my java program?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a GUI in java. I am adding buttons, labels, text fields, and combo boxes. When I run my program, the window that pops up is completely blank. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
public Project3() {
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2));
    leftPanel.setBounds(20, 10, 5, 5);
    leftPanel.add(shapeLbl);
    leftPanel.add(shapeBox);
    leftPanel.add(fillLbl);
    leftPanel.add(fillBox);
    leftPanel.add(colorLbl);
    leftPanel.add(colorBox);
    leftPanel.add(widthLbl);
    leftPanel.add(widthTxt);
    leftPanel.add(heightLbl);
    leftPanel.add(heightTxt);
    leftPanel.add(xLbl);
    leftPanel.add(xTxt);
    leftPanel.add(yLbl);
    leftPanel.add(yTxt);
    add(leftPanel);
       
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setBounds(270, 10, 5, 5);
    rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Shape Drawing"));
    add(rightPanel);
       
    JPanel botPanel = new JPanel();
    botPanel.setBounds(240, 250, 5, 5);
    botPanel.add(drawBtn);
    add(botPanel);
       
    drawBtn.setToolTipText("Using the information above, this button " +
            "draws a shape in the area titled \"Shape Drawing.\"");
    drawBtn.setMnemonic('d');
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Project3 p3 = new Project3();
   p3.setTitle("Geometric Drawing");
   p3.setLayout(null);
   p3.setSize(500, 301);
   p3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   p3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   p3.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: What does `add` do? Where are you adding these panels?

Comment: What class does Project3 extend from?

Comment: Most likely a layout problem.  Remember that a `JFrame` gives itself a `BorderLayout` by default.  So setting bounds has no effect.  Use `setPreferredSize` instead, and specify  `BorderLayout` constraints when adding panels.

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!!

Comment: Also, please give enough of the code to compile it. Half your panels aren't defined at all.

Comment: @NomadMaker Good advice, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre].

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know this. I just wanted to see the complete view-creation routines.